# Why does ggplot stat_function print out only one value with dpois but not with dnorm?

Tags: r, ggplot2, poisson

```
ggplot()+aes(X)+geom_density()+ 
  stat_function(fun = dpois, colour = "red", args = list(lambda=parms$estimate))+
  xlab( "confirmation time [s]") + ggtitle("Shape of curve");
```

leads to:

[image]

but if `args = list(mean = mean(X),sd = sd(X)))` we get a nice normal distribution:

[image]

How can you explain this strange behavior?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28073783/ggplot-poisson-density-curve-why-zigzag-lines. Also, add a reproducible example to your question.